# Keeping margin around div with 100% height

Tags: html, css, positioning

The final ancestor div in my page needs a margin on all four sides, to give it a panel effect. Here is my code:
CSS:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#bibletree {
width: 20%;
float: left;
height: 100%;
}
.inner {  /*this is the div that I need a margin around, so it is by 10px of the #bibletree div on all sides, including the bottom.*/
overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="bibletree">
<div class="inner">my content here, both short and long</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As you probably guessed, there is a lot more going on here than what is written. I have several columns with divs that all need this margin for the panel effect on the `.inner` div. Thanks for any help.
BTW, I have tried absolute positioning and it only positions based on the window, not on the parent element, even if I set the parent to `position: relative`.

Answer (score 1):

If you set .inner to width 100% and add a margin, it will be wider than its container. You can set a padding or a border instead. For example, you can add a white or transparent border of 10px.

Another option is to make #bibletree position relative, then make .inner position absolute and  specify top, bottom, right and left:

```
.inner {
    bottom: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This will make it the same size as #bibletree, minus 10px on every side.

Comment: I did the second thing you mentioned and it positions the `.inner` based on the window, *not* the parent.

Comment: Further, I cannot do the border idea, because when it overflows the scrollbar is *inside* the border.

Comment: You need to make the parent (#bibletree) have `position: relative`, this makes the absolute positioning relative to that element.

Comment: I have and it still stretches the `.inner` element across the whole window

Comment: looking at your jsfiddle and my code I cannot see any difference. Obviously, the jsfiddle works, but what I have doesn't

Comment: ok, b/c I was using `.inner` as a class, it was making every div with that class absolute, even those which didn't have the same parent. I guess I can just use ids instead and control them individually, since there are only three. The only other question is, if the content does not fill the #inner div, I would like it to not extend to the bottom of the parent. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Margin:10px is working right?? you need not no specify the width for inner div, as div is already has block option. check here updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/QShRZ/5/

Comment: yes, *but* if the content extends past the parent there is no margin at bottom. see http://jsfiddle.net/QShRZ/1/

Comment: I see that. But all parents must not exceed the window height, which is why I did `html body` height 100% first. `#bibletree` is not to extend lower than the window.

Comment: Then you can remove min-height from #bibletree